# Get View HTML from Inside a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Model class named "QuoteModel" and a method inside there named "SendEmail" that sends an email.  I have a partial view named "Disclaimer" that is just html (no razor or model).  Is there a way to get the view's html as a string from inside the "SendEmail" function?

I've tried finding the answer, but most answers have to do with getting the html from inside a controller versus model.

Comment: do you want to send an email with views html as the email's body ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back.  Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 3):

use this ready-made function

```
   public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
      ViewData.Model = model;
      using (var sw = new StringWriter())
      {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                 viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                     ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
      }
    }
```

and call it as

```
string result =  RenderRazorViewToString("Disclaimer", QuoteModel);
```

and [this article would be helpful RenderRazorViewToString](http://www.codemag.com/article/1312081)

Please do the needed minor modification accordingly

Comment: When I place that in my method it can't resolve the "RazorViewToString() call.  I must be missing something:[code]

Comment: Here's my model and method
[code]

public class QuoteModel
{
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        string result = RazorViewToString.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "Disclaimer", null);
    }
}
[/code}

Comment: check the updated answer & let me know the results ASAP